# Python/Pandas: Comparing two string columns from different CSV files that are of different lengths and finding where the data is the same

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV files that contain items that accomplish a specific task. I want to see if within these two files there are items that are in both of the data frames. The data frames are of different lengths so I've run into some trouble. The location of the same item on the other list may be 20 items lower than where it is on the first. I would assume the best way to handle this would be to take one item in the first data frame, compare it to all values on the second to see if any are matching, and then if it matches to one, place that into a new data frame, and continue with the same process for all of the entries in the first data frame. I am unsure exactly how to code something like this using python/pandas as I am relatively new to the programming world. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
df1=pd.Dataframe({"Chemical Name":     ["Vitamin D", "Resveratrol", "Vitamin C", "Vitamin A", "Vitamin B"],
"Interaction":     ["Increase", "Decrease", "Increase", "Increase", "Increase"]})

df2=pd.Dataframe({"Chemical Name":     ["Vitamin Z", "Vitamin X", "Vitamin Y", "Vitamin D", "Resveratrol", "Vitamin A"],
"Interaction":     ["Increase", "Decrease", "Increase", "Increase", "Decrease", "Increase"]})
```

Could it really be as simple as

```py
print(pd.merge(df1,df2,on="Chemical Name"))
```

The real data has many more columns with more information for each item, although I'm not too sure that matter at the moment. I just want to compare the chemical names to see if they match in the two data frames.

Comment: We can surely help, before that you will need to provide some sample input along  side with excepted output.

Comment: Great one moment while I create sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set.
You add all the elements of the first frame. Then you add those of the second frame.
The set will remove duplicates.

Comment: Could you show an example of the set method in action?

Comment: http://www.python-simple.com/python-langage/set.php